# For Each Cell (but from bottom row, up)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a For Each Cell code which searches through a column and based on the cell value performs the action. This works fine.
My query is, and which I have looked through Google but to no avail, would it possible to search through the column range rather than top to bottom, but from bottom to top? So in the code below it would start at B1000 and work its way up to B1

```
Set rng = Workbooks("NX01").Worksheets(homeleague).Range("B1:B1000")
For Each c In rng.Cells
If c.Value <> "" And c.Value = hometeam Then
*(then desired action)*
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not with `For Each`. Use a row index in a `For rw = 1000 to 1 step -1` type loop.

Comment: `based on the cell value performs the action` Also depending on what you want to do, you may not even want to use a loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FOR` loop as detailed in this [article on MS Excel functions](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/for_next.php), you can iterate through a set of loops very similarly to how you might in other coding languages.

The FOR loop takes the general form:

```
For COUNTER = [INITIAL] To [FINAL] Step [INCREMENT]
{...statements...}
Next [COUNTER]
```

Where counter is The loop counter variable, start is the starting value for counter,  end is the ending value for counter, and increment is the value by which the counter is incremented on each loop.

With this, you can loop through a column in reverse by simply setting:
start to the row # at the bottom of the column
end to the row of the final cell to iterate through (the top)
increment to -1

By setting increment to -1, the loop starts at the value of the final row and decreases the row number by one every loop. Then, in order to access the appropriate cell, instead of referencing the cell as its assigned name 'c' in your code, you would use Cell(COUNTER, column).